# .NET MAUI Option "Color" and "BackgroundColor" gone

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-maui

Somehow visual studio doesn't recognise the options "Color", "TextColor" and "BackgroundColor" anymore after I went back one version in GitHub, its a permanent bug since Reinstalling Visual Studio doesn't fix it.
Does anyone have an Idea on how to fix it?
[image: ProofOfError]
[image]

Comment: What does it say when you hover over these properties

Comment: The property 'BackgroundColor' was not found in type 'Frame'.

Comment: Have you tried removing bin and obj and rebuilding?

Comment: Yes, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Please provide actual code instead of only a (cut off) screenshot. Also, please explain more about the problem and what you've tried to do.

Comment: Also, does VSCode Support MAUI? I thought that's only available in VS 2022

Comment: oops idk why I put code behind it.

Comment: but its all over Visual Studio, its not one specific project.
I cannot use colors in any project

Comment: A link to one of my projects:
https://github.com/Mielesgames/CookieClickerButBetter

Comment: It fixed itself after I installed a new editor somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing JetBrains and opening your file in it once somehow fixes it.
It has no .NET MAUI support, but after you close the program and open Visual studio it somehow works again...
(Don't ask me how that works)

Comment: I need to wait one day before I can accept my own answer, I guess that's some Stack Overflow security